# Manually loading framework elements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've built a templated printing system which creates XPS documents using XAML, via WPF's `CreateVisualsCollator()`:

```
FrameworkElement fe = ...;

using (Package p = Package.Open(...))
using (XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(p))
{
    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
    SerializerWriterCollator col = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();

    Size size = new Size(page size...)
    fe.Measure(size);
    fe.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    fe.UpdateLayout();

    col.Write(fe);
    // fe.IsLoaded is still false here!
}
```

I'm doing this *without* a UI present -- this is actually destined for a Windows service.

I've been doing hacks like calling `UpdateLayout()` manually to perform sizing, and have realized that the reason I'm having to do so is that the controls are never getting their `Loaded` event triggered, and never getting into a loaded state. I've just hit a snag where this has become a problem and my hack no longer works.

Is there a way to manually trigger a proper load for an element and all its children?

Comment: isn't loaded event called inside the initializecomponent method?

Comment: Nope. It is called some time right before rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to attack this from two angles.

First, don't load up your elements directly. Use a ContentControl, which seems to have a better handle on instantiating templates and resolves a number of deep data binding issues:

```
new ContentControl
{
    Content = item,
    ContentTemplate = template
}
```

Next, allow the idle queue to process. This forces various delayed tasks to run that WPF normally queues up for when your window is idle:

```
FrameworkElement element = ...;
element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle);
```